# Parse lines in file using PHP

Tags: php, json, file, parsing, graph

I am trying to graph data from existing `.log` files (or `.txt` file, it doesn't matter).

The file is organised like this.

```
Unixepochtime value value.\n
Unixepochtime value value value value
```

The first line is different as it only has two values after the time, whereas all the following lines (200+ maybe) are exactly the same as the second line seen above.

However these last two values in the second line and following lines are not needed.

The output needs to be in a file or string in the following manner:

```
[unixepochtime, value], [unixepochtime, value]
```

Of course there will be one for every line though, so to make that clear, the string above would cover two lines of data.

For the second value in the file, it needs to have the same unixepochtime as was on its line, but be written in the format above in another string.

Can this work for files with an unknown amount of lines also? I'm using `Flot`, if that helps. Can this code also work for files with only one value following the time please?

Comment: Everything you want can be done for sure, but have you tried something and can you show some of your code ?

Comment: Please show us what you have done already

Comment: This is the code that I had:       <?php $homepage =     file_get_contents('http://rls.itcglobal.net.au/shelf058/pdu_environ.log');

$time = (substr("$homepage", 0, 10) * 1000) + 28800000;
$humid = substr("$homepage", 11, 5);
$temp = substr("$homepage", 17);
$realhumidity = $humid / 1000;
$realtemperature = $temp / 1000;

echo "[$time, $realhumidity], [$time, $realtemperature]";
$data = ", [$time, $realhumidity]";

echo $data;

$myFile = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$pathToLogfile = 'logfile.txt';

// Check if file exists.
if(!file_exists($pathToLogfile)) {
  echo('Can not find log file');
  exit;
}

// Extract separate lines.
$logEntries = file($pathToLogfile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMTPY_LINES);
// Build code in lines.
$entries = array();
foreach($logEntries as $logEntry) {
  // Split logline into separate values by whitespace.
  $logLineParts = explode(" ", $logEntry);

  // Check if unix epoch is set.
  if(!isset($logLineParts[0])) {
    echo('Missing unix timestamp...');
    continue;
  }
  $unixTimestamp = $logLineParts[0];

  // Check for all values but unix timestamp.
  for($i = 1; $i < count($logLineParts); ++$i) {
    $entries[] = '[' . $unixTimestamp .', '. $logLineParts[$i] .']';
  }
}

echo('Following log items found: '. implode(', ', $entries));
?>
```

I commented it so I hope you can learn from it (what is the most important thing here!) Should work - although untested...

Comment: Hi thedom, I tried it and it did not work... I tried adding echo "Hello World!"; to the top of the file but that didn't work, whereas in another test.php file that worked just fine.

Comment: thedom it does work very well now, thank you :) Can the second value in the file be written with the same timestamp on its line but separately to the first value? (maybe two strings, one for each value)

Comment: I'm not sure if I am explaining myself well but each line has one timestamp and four values following it, the last two of which I'm not interested in. Can the second value still be in the same format with its appropriate timestamp, but in a different string to the first value? Thank you :)

Comment: I managed to do it myself :) I changed $entries to not logLineParts $i but to logLineParts 1, and then did another one for logLineParts 2. Thanks for your help, couldn't be better.